# How to use "if else" or "case when" in JPQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have a query in MySQL like this:

```
SELECT am.*
FROM bettha_adherence_area_manager am
         INNER JOIN bettha_adherence_area aa ON am.bettha_adherence_area_id = aa.id
         INNER JOIN selection_process sp ON aa.selection_process_id = sp.selection_process_id
         INNER JOIN company_country cc ON sp.company_country_id = cc.company_country_id
         INNER JOIN bettha_adherence_area_manager_execution baame
                    on am.bettha_adherence_area_manager_id = baame.bettha_adherence_area_manager_id
WHERE cc.company_country_id = :companyCountryId
  AND (LOWER(am.email) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :search, '%')) OR
       LOWER(am.full_name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :search, '%')))
  AND IF(:isFinished IS NOT NULL, IF(baame.finished_date IS NOT NULL, :isFinished, NOT :isFinished), TRUE)
GROUP BY am.email;
```

Or like this:

```
SELECT am.* FROM bettha_adherence_area_manager am
               INNER JOIN bettha_adherence_area aa ON am.bettha_adherence_area_id = aa.id
               INNER JOIN selection_process sp ON aa.selection_process_id = sp.selection_process_id
               INNER JOIN company_country cc ON sp.company_country_id = cc.company_country_id
               INNER JOIN bettha_adherence_area_manager_execution baame on am.bettha_adherence_area_manager_id = baame.bettha_adherence_area_manager_id
            WHERE cc.company_country_id = :companyCountryId AND
               (LOWER(am.email) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :search, '%')) OR
               LOWER(am.full_name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :search, '%'))) AND
               CASE WHEN (:isFinished IS NOT NULL) THEN (
                   CASE WHEN (baame.finished_date IS NOT NULL) THEN
                       (:isFinished)
                   ELSE
                       NOT :isFinished END
               )
               ELSE TRUE END
            GROUP BY am.email;
```

Both queries do the same thing. I'd like to convert one of these queries to JPQL, but "if else" doesn't exist in JPQL and "case when" doesn't work that way.

How do this query in JPQL?

Answer (score 1):

Try using OR AND in case of if else or case when i.e.,

```
CASE WHEN (:isFinished IS NOT NULL) THEN (
      CASE WHEN (baame.finished_date IS NOT NULL) THEN
            (:isFinished)
       ELSE
             NOT :isFinished END
  )
```

This condition can be written as

```
((:isFinished IS NULL) OR (
      ((baame.finished_date IS NOT NULL) AND (:isFinished=1))
             OR
       ((baame.finished_date IS NULL) AND (:isFinished=0))
  )
```

And for the entire JPQL query we need to see the entity classes first because JPQL uses classes instead of table names for writing the queries.